# Downloading - get a callback when received all the request headers

Tags: android, android-ion

I use [ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion) for downloading files in my app. I want to read the response headers, check a particular header and either cancel or continue the download. Of course I can execute the HEAD query, check the header, and then execute the GET query. But I want to execute only one request.

**Is there a way to get a callback when received all the headers, handle them and either continue or cancel the download?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onHeaders callback.

```
.onHeaders(...)
```

https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/builder/RequestBuilder.java#L186

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. Maybe it's better?

```
Ion.getDefault(<Context>).getHttpClient().insertMiddleware(new SimpleMiddleware()
{
    @Override
    public void onHeadersReceived(OnHeadersReceivedDataOnRequestSentData data)
    {
        super.onHeadersReceived(data);
    }
});
```